# Указатели в С++

Tags: c++, указатели

Почитал я несколько статей в Интернете про указатели, но до конца не разобрался.

Вот код:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma hdrstop

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#pragma argsused
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int *pointer;
    *pointer = 1000;
    cout << pointer << endl;
    cout << *pointer << endl;
    cout << &pointer << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Собственно, в чем вопрос: в чем разница между & и разыменованной переменной при выводе (кстати, при компиляции все разное при выводе)?

Comment: >кстати, при компиляции все разное при выводе

ну вот вам и разница. Искренне ваш кэп

Comment: Так почему выводит разное, если & используется для выдачу адреса переменнной?

Comment: @MaximPro блин, ну так вы хотя бы посмотрите, что именно выводит 

    cout << *pointer << endl

а что выводит 

    cout << &pointer << endl

Путем нехитрых логических умозаключений несложно прийти к вводу, что раз вывод в первом случае совпадает с содержимым, которое вы строкой ранее присвоили переменной *pointer, то в первом случае выводится содержимое переменной, а во втором - адрес

Comment: 1db4874<br>
1000<br>
18ff50<br>

Comment: Понятно, что со * это разыменовывание переменной, и мы получим значение в ответ.

Больше волнует вопрос просто вывод без звезды, это тогда что? Адрес? Если да, то почему он отличается от вывода с &?

Comment: *pointer - это собственно значение (ну это понятно). Ваша перем енная pointer должна быть как-то инициализирована (чего у вас в коде кстати нет), например так: 

    pointer = new int(); 

Тем самым просто pointer будет хранить адрес той ячейки памяти, которая была выделена оператором new. А вот &pointer - это уже адрес самого pointer (в котором в свою очередь, хранится адрес выделенной ранее памяти)

Comment: Ну, если хотите, можно написать и так:

    int *pointer = new int(1000);

Собственно, при выводе будет то же самое...

Что насчет вашего объяснения, я до сих пор в догадках, я не особо понимаю текстовую запись и аморфность, мне бы рисунок, который исчерпывающе показывает суть того, как различаются те вещи, про которые я написал.

Comment: >мне бы рисунок, который исчерпывающе показывает суть того, как различаются те вещи, про которые я написал

Извините, конечно, но вам, может, еще кино снять про особенности указателей? Все вполне прозрачно: 

    cout << pointer;  // выводит адрес памяти, выделенной оператором new 
    cout << *pointer; // содержимое, памяти, та самая 1000
    cout << &pointer; // адрес самого pointer (переменная же где-то должна храниться, не так ли?)

Comment: *  - обратное действие к &

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты создаешь указатель на указатель и удивляешься, что он не совпадает с данными... %)

Советую побольше писать программ на С и почаще использовать указатели. Через некоторое время это станет естественным, как дышать. Возможно, вот такая "картинка" все прояснит:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int data = 1000;
    int* pointer = &data;
    int** pointer_to_pointer = &pointer;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", data, *pointer, **pointer_to_pointer);
    printf("%p %p\n", (void*)pointer, (void*)*pointer_to_pointer);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)pointer_to_pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

Для практических задач, чтобы набить руку, можно использовать сайт CodeAbbey.com

Comment: где я создал указатель на указатель и удивляюсь?

Comment: Для:

    int *p;

результатом операции:

    &p

как раз и будет так называемый указатель на указатель.

Т.е. для сохранения ее значения нужна такая переменная:

    int **pp;

Comment: То есть если я делаю ссылку на указатель через & то что я получаю? Если я правильно понимаю то просто вывод pointer это его адрес(адрес указателя в памяти). А вот с & тогда возникают вопросы... Я просто только начал читать тему указатели и пока у меня одно чувство - смятение
Как выходит что & это указатель на указатель?
Если напишите понятно(сделайте как ответ), я выберу как ответ на мой вопрос, потому что то что вы написали более адекватнее звучит

Comment: @MaximPro, в комментарии к своему ответу @elCorsaiR правильно написал о памяти и адресах. По сути добавить  нечего.

Видимо тут все дело в терминологии и синонимах 

(указатель и адрес это в известном смысле синонимы, существенная разница в том, что указатель *типизирован*. Если мы прибавим к значению указателя 1, то адрес, на который он указывает (т.е. значение указателя как числа) увеличится не на 1, а на размер типа переменной, которую адресует указатель).

Лучше, конечно, почитать об этом подробнее, например, в известной книжке -- K&R.

Comment: @MaximPro: Я же все расписал, причем именно через &. Мог бы обратить внимание, что pointer получился именно как &data. То есть & - это адрес. Указатель - это переменная, в которой записан адрес чего-либо.

Может, тебе и правда нарисовать? Вот есть ящик, в котором лежит 1000 рублей (а лучше долларов). Ящик называется data. Оператор & дает координаты ящика data (например, десятый от стены). Но этот номер - тоже данные. Для них тоже нужен ящик (переменная). Назовем этот ящик pointer. Тогда &pointer - его порядковый номер. А вот *pointer - это данные из ящика, адрес которого лежит в ящике pointer

Comment: Не надо мне объяснять унарную операцию &, я же не ДЦП, чтобы не понимать смысл и значение операции

Comment: Только сейчас заметил этот комментарий, иначе бы даже не отвечал. Человек демонстрирует тотальное непонимание (и нежелание понять) простейших вещей, в том числе операции &, но при этом не забыл продемонстрировать свои фашистские комплексы. К твоему сведение, люди с ДЦП могут быть вполне дееспособными и даже высокоинтеллектуальными (у нас в институте училась девушка с ДЦП). Человека создает то, что он делает, а не то, какой он. Почитай Ильенкова, Монтессори, Дуэк...


Еще большой вопрос, что хуже - ДЦП или Синдром Даннинга-Крюгера. У человека с ДЦП есть шанс стать умным, у человека с СДК - нет

Answer (score 1):

> cout << pointer << endl;

- адрес, по которому хранится твое значение

> cout << &pointer << endl;

- адрес, по которому хранится сам указатель (типа адрес, указывающий на место, где хранится адрес, по которому хранится твое значение).

Comment: значение чего? цифры? 1000?

Comment: ага, 1000.

Comment: если я правильно понимаю, то вывод следующий:  
1) У нас есть указатель, у которого уже есть значение 1000, допустим.
2) Адрес на указатель свой.  
3) Адрес на значение указателя тоже свой.  
Так что ли?  
Выше пишут, что &pointer это указатель на указатель.
Я совсем запутался.

Comment: Не совсем. начнем с того, что у нас есть память, у каждой ячейки памяти есть адрес, и в этой ячейке может храниться значение. все переменный располагаются по какому-то адресу и указатели тоже. Из твоего примера:
1db4874 - адрес ячейки памяти, где храниться значение 1000. т.е. если в просмотрщике памяти ты перейдешь на адрес 1db4874, то увидишь там значение 1000.
18ff50 - адрес, где храниться сам указатель. т.е. если в просмотрщике памяти ты перейдешь на адрес 18ff50, то увидишь там значение 1db4874.

Comment: а как это можно посмотреть?

Comment: То есть за все это время ты так и не удосужился посмотреть и запустить мой код? Клиническая картина ясна, тему можно закрывать.

Comment: я компилировал ваш код давно

Comment: Ну и в чем проблема тогда? Иди и пиши программы. Первые десять даже не скомпилируются, еще десять скомпилируются, но будут работать неправильно, а потом ты поймешь указатели. А пока ты только ковыряешь одно и то же, надеясь, что вот-вот, сейчас-сейчас снизойдет озарение.

Рекомендую прочесть книги:
http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/8684879/

http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2468511/

http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/22538533/

Answer (score 1):

Для лучшего понимания лучше писать так:

```
int* pointer;
```

где не  **тип что-то имя**, а **тип имя**, то есть int * лучше считать отдельным "типом".
И если посмотреть на тип нашей переменной, то можно понять, что

```
cout << pointer;
```

возвращает именно *значение* "типа" int *, где &pointer - это адрес, по которому хранится наше* значение*.

Где *значение* - адрес на участок памяти, по которому в ходе выполнения программы будет выделена память для типа int, которое можно получить так:

```
 cout << *pointer;
```

Comment: *pointer - я давно понял как прочитал статью в интернете, меня интересует разница в выводе pointer и &pointer

Comment: Я об этом уже написал(под вторым блоком с кодом)